# SQL: return percentage without decimal place

Tags: mysql

Quick question; is there a way to apply numeric type on select statement?

exmaple usage

```
select (t1.f_count / (select count(*) from utb where user_id = 1))*100 as ratio
```

i need this to returns 60 instead of 60.0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
select ROUND((t1.f_count / (select count(*) from utb where user_id = 1))*100) as ratio
```